# How to access parent view variable without passing as binding in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding

I am using `showCommentView` variable which is `@State` variable which i am passing in subview as `@Binding` the problem here is for every subview i need to pass as binding. How can i achieve it independently

```
struct AudioListView: View {

    @State var showCommentView = false 
   SecondView(showCommentView: $showCommentView)
}

struct SecondView {
    @Binding var showCommentView:Bool
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want an [EnvironmentObject](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views)

Comment: @aheze you are right Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass `showCommentView` variable as binding as following :

```
struct AudioListView: View {
   @State var showCommentView = false 
   SecondView(showCommentView: .constant(showCommentView))
}

struct SecondView {
   @Binding var showCommentView:Bool
}
```

If you want to use is `@State` or as `@Binding` you can use it as you want